# Why does this Combine subscription not cause a retain cycle?

Tags: swiftui, automatic-ref-counting, combine

I noticed this was triggering the deinit block even without weak/unowned used. I simplified the code to show what is happening.

```
final class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var isLoading = false
    private var cancellables: [AnyCancellable] = []

    var randomPublisher: AnyPublisher<Void, Never> {
        Just(()).eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }

    func someAction() {
        randomPublisher.sink { completion in
            self.isLoading = false                
            switch completion {
                case .finished:
                break
            }
        } receiveValue: { _ in  }
        .store(in: &cancellables)
    }
}

struct SampleView: View {
    @StateObject private var viewModel = ViewModel()
}
```

I would think there is a reference cycle when `someAction()` is called as self is captured inside the subscription and the viewmodel holds the subscription array. It's successfully accessing the deinit block when view is dismissed so why is that the case whereas in other viewmodels I need to make self weak in the same place?

Comment: Because `Just` completes almost immediately, and the subscription (probably) releases its resources, like the completion closure

Comment: Ah ok thanks - in the real code it’s a future that is called. Which I guess behaves similarly. Would you suggest leaving a weak self in the subscription for good practice?

Comment: it's hard to be certain in without concrete code, but yeah - I don't see a downside, not to mention that a future might never happen, which would cause a leak